Count read and written bytes in a Duplex stream in Node.JS
I have a Duplex stream object coming from a library that I'm piping into HTTP requests so the request and the response goes through it.
From https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html:

Node.js versions and provides multiple methods of consuming stream
data. In general, developers should choose one of the methods of
consuming data and should never use multiple methods to consume data
from a single stream. Specifically, using a combination of on('data'),
on('readable'), pipe(), or async iterators could lead to unintuitive
behavior.

I would like to know the total amount of bytes read and written.
const req = http.request({
    createConnection: () => {
        const duplexStream = getDuplexStreamFromLibrary();
        // TODO: Count read and written bytes in `duplexStream`
        return duplexStream;
    }
});

req.on("response", (res) => {
    res.pipe(anotherStream);
});

How can I do it?

You can create a transform stream and then apply a pipeline to the streams.
const { Transform, pipeline } = require('node:stream');

let bytes = 0;
let byteCtr = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    bytes += Buffer.byteLength(chunk);
    this.push(chunk);
    callback();
  }
});

http.request(
  { ...,
    (res) => {
      pipeline(res, byteCtr, otherLib, (err) => {
        if(err)
          console.error(err);
        else
          console.log(`Got ${bytes} bytes`);
      });
    }
  }
);



This seems to only count the received bytes coming from the response. I also want to count sent bytes coming through the request's duplex stream.

Was just trying to show you the basics of what you need. If you want to count the bytes in the other direction as well, just create an additional stream that does that separately.
